# Grabbing the current Flexslider image's title tag

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to grab the title tag of the current slide within my Flexslider setup. 
I'm trying:

```
var title = $('li.flex-active-slide').find('img').attr("alt"); 
$('.slidetitles').text(title);
```

It grabs the first slide but does not continue updating.

Comment: We need to see some outputted HTML

Comment: You need to find the event that causes one slide to transition to another, and hook on it.

Comment: Yeaup, that code was correct. It needed to go into the .flexslider function. I had it alone. Newb...